# Is there a way to remove the hh:mm from moment.js, moment().add(2, 'days').calendar()?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to show only the day of the week as a result and I'm looking for a built in format method in moment.js before I use reg ex for the job.

What I get:

```
moment().add(2, 'days').calendar() = "Thursday at 12:46 PM"
```

What I need is to get only "Thursday"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using `calendar`, you want to use `format`:

```
moment().add(2, 'days').format('dddd') // "Thursday"
```

The API docs explain that `calendar` gives [the date compared to a reference date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/), whereas `format` allows you to [format the date how you like](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).